# adding numbers from database

Tags: android, database

I have 2 separate `Activities` with  some calculations. These calculations are stored in the database. Now I want one new `Activity` if user click add button.It should add both final calculations of both `Activities` and it should display in single `TextView`.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

---

I have 3 calculation fields in each activity I have total summary=200, total material=100,total price=200. Same as in second activity also I have same fields with different calculations.

All those values are stored in database now I have new activity with button when we click on that button it should add the both calculations and ans should display in single textview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 'add button' location. Suggesting it's in both activities You've mentioned.

1. If You have provider attached to the database (which is the right Android way per my understanding): I would suggest to use [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) in add button `OnClickListener` to launch query to obtain data from database. In callback of AsyncQueryHandler do calculation and pass them as extras (using `Intent.putExtra()`) to launch intent for new activity;
2. If You have no provider attached: I would suggest to launch `Thread` in add button `OnClickListener`. In that `Thread` do query and launch new activity by passing calculated data via intent extra.